# Context Menu for user setup on first use?

Tags: android, menu

I'm trying to set up a menu that appears when the user starts the app for the 1st time, so they can set it up by choosing from 1 of 6 items. It needs to start automatically dependent on a boolean value taken from sharedPreferences. 
I have been trying to create a context menu, but its not working and I'm not sure if its the right way to go about it. 
Has anyone done this and is context menu the right way to go? If not, please could you point me in the right direction.
Many thanks

Comment: Yes, thank you Nicholas, that would seem to be the way to go :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using a ContextMenu for this kind of design. You should be using a Custom Dialog for the configuring of your app. Using perhaps a ViewSlider to allow multiple configuration screens or just one View with all the configuration options in a ScrollView.